# Xamarin.Android: Decrypted Files Randomly Being Corrupted

Tags: android, xamarin, encryption

I have an application that encrypts files for storage purposes and decrypts them for uploading to our server.  For the most part it works fine and the decrypted files we receive are good files.

However, on a semi-regular basis (one or two files out of a few hundred every few days) the decrypted files are corrupt.  It's possible that the original files were corrupt as well and the issue was not in the encrypt/decrypt process, but this has occurred to different users who presumably would have made sure that the files weren't corrupt to begin with, but I don't know how to verify this as I do not have direct contact with our users.

I want to make sure that my code is not the source of the problem, or if there is something I can do to check that the files were safely encrypted/decrypted in the application to make sure all the files we receive are good.

What is strange is that I have an ExceptionManager class that sends me any exceptions that occur, and I do not receive any exceptions when these corrupt files get processed and uploaded, so I have no way of knowing what went wrong.

This is my Encrypt code:

```
static string aesTransform = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"
public static bool EncryptFile(Context context, string fileLocation, ref string encryptedFileLocation)
{
            bool success;            
            try
            {
                Log logger = new Log(context);
                logger.Debug("starting encryption");
                if (File.Exists(fileLocation))
                {
                    encryptedFileLocation = (encryptedFileLocation ?? fileLocation) + ".aes";

                    using (FileStream fInput = File.Open(fileLocation, FileMode.Open))
                    using (FileStream fOutput = File.Open(encryptedFileLocation, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))                        
                    {
                        byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptKey);
                        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, 0, keyBytes.Length, "AES");
                        Cipher cipher = Cipher.GetInstance(aesTransform);
                        cipher.Init(CipherMode.EncryptMode, key, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[cipher.BlockSize]));

                        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fOutput, cipher);                        
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        int numBytesWritten = 0;
                        while ((numBytesWritten = fInput.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            cos.Write(buffer, 0, numBytesWritten);
                        }
                        cos.Flush();
                        cos.Close();                        
                    }

                    logger.WriteLog(Log.LogType.Misc, fileLocation + " encrypted");
                    Delete(context, fileLocation);                                                            
                }
                success = true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                if (File.Exists(fileLocation) && File.Exists(encryptedFileLocation))
                {
                    Delete(context, encryptedFileLocation);
                }
                if(encryptedFileLocation.EndsWith(".aes"))
                {
                    encryptedFileLocation = encryptedFileLocation.Remove(encryptedFileLocation.ToUpper().LastIndexOf(".AES"));
                }   
                ex.Data.Add("fileLocation", fileLocation);
                ex.Data.Add("encryptedFileLocation", encryptedFileLocation);
                ExceptionManager.ManageException(context, ex);
                success = false;
            }
            return success;
        }
```

And this is my Decrypt Code:

```
static string aesTransform = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"
public static bool DecryptFile(Context context, string fileLocation, ref string decryptedFileLocation)
        {
            bool decrypted = false;
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(fileLocation))
                {
                    if(fileLocation.ToUpper().EndsWith(".AES"))
                    {
                        decryptedFileLocation = fileLocation.Remove(fileLocation.ToUpper().LastIndexOf(".AES"));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        decryptedFileLocation = fileLocation;
                    }

                    using (FileStream fInput = File.Open(fileLocation, FileMode.Open))
                    using (FileStream fOutput = File.Open(decryptedFileLocation, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                    {
                        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(fileLocation);
                        byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptKey);
                        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, 0, keyBytes.Length, "AES");                        
                        Cipher cipher = Cipher.GetInstance(aesTransform);
                        cipher.Init(CipherMode.DecryptMode, key, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[cipher.BlockSize]));
                        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fInput, cipher);
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        int numBytesWritten = 0;
                        while ((numBytesWritten = cis.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            fOutput.Write(buffer, 0, numBytesWritten);
                        }
                        cis.Close();
                        decrypted = true;                        
                        Log logger = new Log(context);
                        logger.WriteLog(Log.LogType.Misc, fileLocation + " decrypted");                        
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (File.Exists(fileLocation) && File.Exists(decryptedFileLocation))
                {
                    Delete(context, decryptedFileLocation);
                }                
                decryptedFileLocation = fileLocation;
                ex.Data.Add("fileLocation", fileLocation);
                ExceptionManager.ManageException(context, ex);
                decrypted = false;
            }
            return decrypted;
        }
```

The encrypt key is identical for both Encrypt and Decrypt methods, both referencing a static string declared earlier in this class, so the keys match.

Comment: Hi , welcome to SO ! I don't think the problem lies in the code of encryption and decryption. I don't know if the frequency of encryption and decryption is too fast. This will cause some files to be terminated before the encryption is completed. If this is the case, it is recommended to use async / await to implement asynchronous encryption. You can refer to [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/getting-started-with-async-await/).

Comment: First off, it's great to finally be a part of the SO community! Thanks!  @Junior Jiang could you elaborate on what you mean by the frequency is too fast causing files to terminate early?  Why would the encryption terminate? And how would this be solved by encrypting asynchronously?

Comment: After a read through I don't see anything wrong. I also don't see any issue that are caused by, or can be solved by, asynchronous constructs. How are these corruption events being identified? Most of the time, with `PKCS5Padding`, *if* the ciphertext file has been corrupted than decryption will fail with a `BadPaddingException`. This is not guaranteed however. If you are getting corruption events occasionally but never getting a `BadPaddingException` then I'd guess the data was corrupted before it was encrypted.

Comment: Consider switching to an authenticated encryption method like AES-GCM, and use an actual random IV/nonce for each encryption. Prepend the IV/nonce to the ciphertext on encryption and strip it off prior to decryption. With GCM and a 16 byte MAC, corrupted ciphertext will *always* be detected.

Comment: @JeffreyBeitsch I agree with James's points . If async/await can not be the reason , there is another reason is that the file is corrupted berfore be encrypted . I think you should check whehter the file is corrupted after storing in local first .

Comment: @James Can you provide me with a code example of how to encrypt/decrypt using AES-GCM the way you described?